# Get specific values from XML in c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<result>
    <resourceName>customEntityEntry</resourceName>
    <size>8</size>
    <entries>
        <entry id="32537965" 
               link="/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537965.xml"/>
        <entry id="32537966" 
               link="/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537966.xml"/>
        <entry id="32537967" 
               link="/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537967.xml"/>
        <entry id="32537972" 
               link="/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537972.xml"/>
        <entry id="32537975" 
               link="/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537975.xml"/>
        <entry id="32537978" 
               link="/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537978.xml"/>
        <entry id="32537979" 
               link="/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537979.xml"/>
        <entry id="32537981" 
               link="/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537981.xml"/>
    </entries>
</result>
```

I have this XML above and need to get only the "link" value of each entry, for `example/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537965.xml`. This need to be done dynamically, because the number of entries will vary.

I tried using `System.XML` and regex, but had no success.

Comment: try using [xpath](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308333/how-to-query-xml-with-an-xpath-expression-by-using-visual-c)

Comment: It really would help us if you showed what you “tried using” as that will tell us what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: You could also use [linq to xml](https://www.google.com/search?q=linq+to+xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way would be to use Linq To XML. ie:

```
string xml = @"<result>
<resourceName>customEntityEntry</resourceName>
<size>8</size>
<entries>
<entry id=""32537965"" 
link=""/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537965.xml""/>
<entry id=""32537966"" 
link=""/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537966.xml""/>
<entry id=""32537967"" 
link=""/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537967.xml""/>
<entry id=""32537972"" 
link=""/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537972.xml""/>
<entry id=""32537975"" 
link=""/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537975.xml""/>
<entry id=""32537978"" 
link=""/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537978.xml""/>
<entry id=""32537979"" 
link=""/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537979.xml""/>
<entry id=""32537981"" 
link=""/customEntity/88336/customEntityEntry/32537981.xml""/>
</entries>
</result>
";


var links = XElement.Parse(xml)
   .DescendantsAndSelf()
   .Where(xe => xe.Attribute("link") != null)
   .Select(xe => (string)xe.Attribute("link"));
```